# ruby script display errors but continue

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0

I am trying to run multiple lines of completely independent code where any line could throw an error. How can I get the script to run (with or without logging errors) until it is completed without stopping? I am trying to avoid using begin/rescue on every line

Some of the (many) lines I am trying to run:

```
Steam.apikey = '8_____1' #http://steamcommunity.com/dev/apikey
$stdout.reopen("playergamedump.csv", "w")
id= Steam::User.vanity_to_steamid("MEEE")
badges_hash= Steam::Player.badges(id)
puts "###BADGES###"
puts badges_hash
steam_level=Steam::Player.steam_level(id)
puts "###STEAM LEVEL###"
puts steam_level
....
```

Comment: May I ask what the individual lines are doing? Maybe there's another way of solving your problem.

Comment: Added example, hope it helps!

Comment: begin; rescue around the whole set of lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of a way around this without using `begin`/`rescue` on every line. However, your example shows that some lines depend on the result on the previous line and thus make no sense to be executed when the previous line failed. Also, the first few lines with the basic setup might as well raise an exception, because without the `id`, the rest of the file will probably fail as well.

You could wrap the blocks that make sense in a `begin`/`rescue` block, then print a message to stderr (or do something else) if it fails:

```
Steam.apikey = '8_____1' #http://steamcommunity.com/dev/apikey
$stdout.reopen("playergamedump.csv", "w")
id = Steam::User.vanity_to_steamid("MEEE")

begin
  badges_hash = Steam::Player.badges(id)
  puts "###BADGES###"
  puts badges_hash
rescue StandardError
  $sterr.puts "Failed to get badges"
end

begin
  steam_level = Steam::Player.steam_level(id)
  puts "###STEAM LEVEL###"
  puts steam_level
rescue StandardError
  $sterr.puts "Failed to get steam_level"
end
```

If the rest of the file looks the same, you might as well go ahead and remove the duplication by storing the names of the user properties in an array and dynamically requesting them with `public_send`:

```
Steam.apikey = '8_____1' #http://steamcommunity.com/dev/apikey
$stdout.reopen("playergamedump.csv", "w")
id = Steam::User.vanity_to_steamid("MEEE")

[
  :badges,
  :steam_level,
  ...
].each do |property|
  begin
    value = Steam::Player.public_send(property, id)
    title = property.tr('_', ' ').upcase
    puts "####{title}###"
    puts value
  rescue StandardError
    $sterr.puts "Failed to get #{property}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can as suggested just put a begin .. rescue around the whole block, or you can also do something like this:

```
begin
  # one or more lines of code
rescue firstPotentialExecption
  # one or lines of code 
rescue nextPotentialExecption
  # ...
else
  # AnyOtherExecptions
end
```

Or you can just try to figure out what exception you get at the very end and only have the one rescue statement.